# How to access Parameter Value of public method inside private method

Tags: c#, winforms

can I pass `EditQuestionMaster(int qid_value)` this `qid_value` ,within this `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` button click ,if yes than how can i do this so that I can `UpdateQuestion` properly

```
public partial class EditQuestionMaster : Form
    {
        DbHandling db = new DbHandling();
        public EditQuestionMaster(int qid_value)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string subNtop = db.GetEditSubNTopic(qid_value);
            string[] subNtopData = subNtop.Split('~');
            cmbSubject.Text = subNtopData[2];                
        }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       

            int qid = ; //here i want the value of int qid_value
            string AnsOp = "";
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
                AnsOp = "1";
            else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
                AnsOp = "2";
            else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
                AnsOp = "3";
            else if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
                AnsOp = "4";
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Answer Option Not Selected");
                return;
            }

            string Marks = cmbMarks.SelectedItem.ToString();

            if (db.UpdateQuestion(qid, txtQuestion.Text, txtOption1.Text, txtOption2.Text, txtOption3.Text, txtOption4.Text, AnsOp, Marks, "T"))
                MessageBox.Show("Question Updated Successfully");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to Update Question");   
        }
}
```

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: use a class variable, you have already done so with your `DBhandling db` variable...just do it again for the qid value

Comment: I am getting that qid_value from another form ,so how to use class variable for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public partial class EditQuestionMaster : Form
    {
        DbHandling db = new DbHandling();
        int qid; // here is the class variable
        public EditQuestionMaster(int qid_value)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.qid = qid_value; // set the value here

            string subNtop = db.GetEditSubNTopic(qid_value);
            string[] subNtopData = subNtop.Split('~');
            cmbSubject.Text = subNtopData[2];                
        }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       

            qid // use it here
```

Comment: While this answers the OP question, it is not truly "passing a value" into the click event handler. The difference is subtle but important. You are instead creating state inside the form. This means any other code inside the form could change the ID without the button click handler knowing about it. This may or may not be an issue. The better solution would be to create a business object which handles the updates and reference that object from the form.

Comment: @Jay hmm I havent heard of `business objects` but what you said makes sense.  Seems like I have some research to do.

Comment: yes this answers my question,but still can you please show me how i can create a business object that handles the updates as you have said

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on chancea's answer:

You can define a business object to handle the updates like so:

```
public class QuestionEditor
{
    DbHandling db = new DbHandling();
    int questionId;
    public QuestionEditor(int questionId)
    {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

    public void SetAnswer(string answerOption)
    {
        db.UpdateQuestion(qid, answerOption);
    }
}
```

When your form is created, have it create a new instance of your business object:

```
public partial class EditQuestionMaster : Form
{
    QuestionEditor editor;
    public EditQuestionMaster(int qid_value)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        editor = new QuestionEditor(qid_value);            
    }
}
```

Now other methods in your form can call into the editor to perform operations.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string answerOption;

    // switch populates answerOption

    editor.SetAnswer(answerOption);
}
```

By moving your logic to perform updates away from the form where the user interacts is called an abstraction. This abstraction allows the UI code to evolve somewhat independently of how the question data is accessed/stored. This is the basis for n-Tier architecture.

Comment: My intent here is not to take away from chancea's answer, as his is perfectly valid and answers the OP question. My intent is to steer the OP away from some potentially dangerous design habits. And hope that I can help show the beauty and elegance of C#.

Comment: yes I got The point You want to show ,thanks for showing good design  habit ,but i have to study it bit more ,thank you

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: `DBHandling db` which i am already using can it be called business object ? because in `DBHandling Class` I did the same thing like u did in `QuestionEditor class`

Comment: Not really. DbHandling should know everything about how to work with your data, but it shouldn't know what is done with it outside of simply reading and writing, thats what the business object is for. To the same point, the business object should not know that the answer comes from a radio button (etc), just that the value of the answer has changed.